# Python use of itertools to find all combinations / permutations (with replacement)

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am sure this I am missing the point.  Simple code:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

p1 = combinations_with_replacement("2357",3)
y = [''.join(i) for i in p1]
print (y)
```

Produces:  ['222', '223', '225', '227', '233', '235', '237', '255', '257', '277', '333', '335', '337', '355', '357', '377', '555', '557', '577', '777']

I am looking to find all possible ways of pulling 3 from the 4 digits - where order matters.  In my case, 755 is not returned as 557 has the same digits.

I am looking for:
['222','223','232' (new), '225', 252' (new) ] etc

Currently the use of combinations_with_replacement rejects sequences where the numbers have been previously drawn.   I probably need "permutations" (but with replace) which seems to be missing.

What am I overlooking?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) since you seem to be looking for the entire cartesian product `pool X pool X pool`:

```
from itertools import product

p1 = product("2357", repeat=3)
y = [*map(''.join, p1)]
print(y)
```

Comment: Perfect - only ever used product for two lists.   Works perfectly.  Thank you.